# Multiple DHCP Servers - can each supply addressess to 'local' clients only?

Tags: router, dhcp

I have read the canonical question [Can I have multiple DHCP servers on one network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/368512/can-i-have-multiple-dhcp-servers-on-one-network), and have a follow up question.

A simplified explanation of my setup...

```
client1 ----- router1 ----------------- router2 ----- client2
```

Essentially, I would like client1 to get an address from router1 (& client2 from router2).
These clients download firmware from a TFTP server on the router they're connected directly to (TFTP address is same as default gateway address), so I don't want client1 getting firmware from router2 when it is connected directly to router1.

The reason for this logic is that if router2 were to fail, client2 could be connected directly to router1, and would then get it's firmware from router1 without any further configuration. Vice versa if router1 failed. I want DHCP for this reason. (There are also more than 2 routers in reality)

Can anyone suggest how I could implement this please.
If there is a far more straightforward way to accomplish the same, please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: routers are interconnected via ethernet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make each router provide DHCP services locally, by default Client2 *couldn't* get an address from Router1 or vice versa, they clients will only get addresses from their local routers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have set up these routers, but my devices are getting IP addresses from a router other than the one it's directly physically connected to.

Comment: I got this working when I set up routing between my routers, rather than linking with a switch. Thanks for your answer.