# Multiple DHCP on the network

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

I work in a company where two companies are under one network. They use same subnet. (We have 50 clients (pc) - 4 servers - total for both companies)

Both companies have own server for domain controller, each company have own employees.

I was wondering is it good solution to set main router (default gateway) to serve as only DHCP, and to remove DHCP from domain controllers ?

Only servers have static IP address. It is hard to manage multiple DHCP servers. Especially in this case where employees use WIFI connection as well

Router model - CISCO RV325  Gigabit Dual WAN VPN Router

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/368512/can-i-have-multiple-dhcp-servers-on-one-network

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a single DHCP server in a single L2 network. Otherwise unexpected things will happen. Since your question lacks details on network configuration, more detailed answer cannot be given here.